# Postgres 9.2 database asks for password despite open trust settings

Tags: postgresql, authentication, passwords, webserver

I am new to using postgres and I am trying to access a database running on a webserver on which I have no root access.

My problem is, that I am always asked for passwords when trying to interact with the database or access it, although the authentication is set to `trust` for all users and databases.

After installing postgres 9.2 from source in my home directory, I successfully iniciated a database cluster using `initdb -U thisuser -D tmpdb -A trust`, where `thisuser` is the user name I have on the webserver. During this I am logged in via ssh to the server.

Also starting the server was no problem using `pg_ctl -D tmpdb start`.

However, when I try to access the database using `psql -U postgres` it always asks for a password.

From what I understood this should not happen, as I allow connection from all users and databases. The configuration files are in the database cluster floder: `tmpdb/pg_hba.conf` and `tmpdb/postgresql.conf`.

The server is set to `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` and the authentication setting is the following:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I have played around with the settings a lot, but I can not find out how I can actually access the database once it is set up. How can I get acccess?

thanks in advance!

EDIT SOLVED:

I am not sure what exactly was going on before, but I had to set an environment variable as follows:

```
PGPORT = 5433
export PGPORT
```

where 5433 is the port specified in the `postgresql.conf` file. Now it works fine... (Thanks @celenius).

Comment: How do you set the environment variable?

Comment: As shown in the answer, the command is `export PGPORT=5433`, you can see if it was set correctly by calling `echo $PGPORT`.

Comment: Do you mean that it is a system environment variable?

Comment: You would need to set this variable from the environment from which postgres is launched. So yes, it works as a system env var, but it does not have to be.

Comment: Thanks, I had been struggling with this.

Answer (score 1):

If `initdb` has been invoked with `-U thisuser`, it is expected that `thisuser` is going to be used as the superuser instead of `postgres`.

Actually maybe `postgres` doesn't even exist as a database user in this case, which would be a good reason why `psql -U postgres` doesn't work. As for why it asks for the password instead of divulging that the user doesn't exist, it's a common response that avoids leaking information about existing accounts to a non-authorized person.

Other than that, the `pg_hba.conf` and the other commands look fine. You should be able to connect password-less with `psql -U thisuser`.

Comment: thanks that's a good point. I also tried logging in as `thisuser` but there was a password request anyway. Neither the password used to login through ssh nor providing no password have helped. I could still not log in...

Comment: Any clue in the server logs? Restart with `pg_ctl -D somewhere -l /path/to/logfile` if you don't have server logs.

Comment: thanks for your help Daniel. Do you by any chance know why this environment variable helped in this case?

Comment: The default PG port is 5432. What's plausible is that there was already a PG server instance listening to this port on the machine where you installed your own instance, so you were trying to connect to the instance that's not yours on port 5432, and this one requires passwords.